# Model custom attributes CRUD with vue/vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

A back end business object contains a custom attributes data structure that allows client to add key/value pairs for persistence in the database. For example: `Map<String, String> customAttributes;`

UI example: (With the ability to add additional rows)
[image]

Within the vue's data function, I have a placeholder for this data:

```
data() {
    return {
      customAttributes: {},
      ...
    }
```

But I cannot figure out a way to bind the UI inputs to the `customAttributes` object such that adding a new row (attribute) adds a corresponding key and value to it.

Is there an alternative way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `Map` for this as Vue will have a hard time tracking object keys if they can be readily altered. Seems more appropriate to use something like `Array<{ key: string, value: string }>`

If you do need the *map* version, you can easily compute it from the array

```js
const model = { key: "", value: "" }

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    attributes: [{
      key: "GRADLE_HOME",
      value: "/usr/local/gradle"
    }, {
      key: "JAVA_HOME",
      value: "/usr/lib/jvm/whatever"
    }]
  }),
  computed: {
    attributeMap: ({ attributes }) =>
      Object.fromEntries(attributes.map(({ key, value }) => [ key, value ]))
  },
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.attributes.push({...model})
    },
    del (index) {
      this.attributes.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(attr, index) in attributes" :key="index">
        <td><input v-model="attr.key"/></td>
        <td>
          <input v-model="attr.value" />
          <button @click="del(index)">&times;</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr><td colspan="2"><button @click="add">Add Attribute</button></td></tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <pre>attributeMap = {{ attributeMap }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! the `Array<{ key: string, value: string }>` was the creativity I was missing. 
I am assuming that is only recommended for the front end? Because `attributeMap` maps perfectly to the Java backends Map<String, String>. Thoughts?